# Enabling/disabling binary flags in GNU Parallel

Tags: bash, zsh, gnu-parallel

I am trying to use GNU Parallel to run a script that has multiple binary flags. I would like to enable/disable these as follows:

Given a script named "`sample.py`", with two options, "`--seed`" which takes an integer and "`--something`" which is a binary flag and takes no input, I would like to construct a call to parallel that produces the following calls:

```
python sample.py --seed 1111
python sample.py --seed 1111 --something
python sample.py --seed 2222
python sample.py --seed 2222 --something
python sample.py --seed 3333
python sample.py --seed 3333 --something
```

I've tried things like

```
parallel python sample.py --seed {1} {2} ::: 1111 2222 3333 ::: "" --something
parallel python sample.py --seed {1} {2} ::: 1111 2222 3333 ::: '' --something
parallel python sample.py --seed {1} {2} ::: 1111 2222 3333 ::: \  --something
```

but haven't had any luck. Is what I'm trying to achieve possible with GNU parallel? I can modify my script to take explicit TRUE/FALSE values for the flag but I'd prefer to avoid that if possible.

Comment: What version of `parallel` is this? Where did you get that `:::` or `{1}` is something that `parallel` understands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are *so* close.

GNU Parallel quotes replacement strings. That usually makes sense, because it is then safe to give it filenames like:

```
My brother's 12" records, all with ***.csv
```

which could otherwise give no end of troubles.

However, to be consistent GNU Parallel also quotes the empty string. And that is what is hitting you here.

`--dry-run` shows what is going on:

```
$ parallel --dry-run python sample.py --seed {1} {2} ::: 1111 2222 3333 ::: '' --something
python sample.py --seed 1111 ''
python sample.py --seed 1111 --something
python sample.py --seed 2222 ''
python sample.py --seed 2222 --something
python sample.py --seed 3333 ''
python sample.py --seed 3333 --something
```

So how can you avoid that?

You can tell the shell to evaluate all strings:

```
parallel eval python sample.py --seed {1} {2} ::: 1111 2222 3333 ::: '' --something
```

but that might be a bit of a blunt hammer when you need a scalpel. From version 20190722 you can also use `{=uq=}`. `uq()` is a perl function which tells GNU Parallel that this replacement string should not be quoted:

```
$ parallel-20190722 --dry-run python sample.py --seed {1} {=2 uq=} ::: 1111 2222 3333 ::: '' --something
python sample.py --seed 1111 
python sample.py --seed 1111 --something
python sample.py --seed 2222 
python sample.py --seed 2222 --something
python sample.py --seed 3333 
python sample.py --seed 3333 --something
```

Comment: Thanks, Ole! Btw, GNU Parallel absolutely rocks. Keep up the good work :)

Answer (score 0):

```
> bash$ cat sample.py 
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import time

time.sleep(0.2)
print(sys.argv)
> bash$ cat split.sh 
#!/bin/sh

exec $*
> bash$ for seed in 1111 2222 3333; do \
    printf "%s\0" "$seed" "$seed --something"; \
done \
| xargs -0 parallel \
    sh split.sh python3 sample.py --
['sample.py', '1111', '--something']
['sample.py', '1111']
['sample.py', '2222']
['sample.py', '2222', '--something']
['sample.py', '3333', '--something']
['sample.py', '3333']
```

Explanation:

The first part, the loop, just creates the list of arguments:

```
1111
1111 --something
2222
2222 --something
3333
3333 --something
```

`xargs` will send that list from stdin to `parallel`'s arguments.

`split.sh` splits its arguments by whitespace - here we're assuming that the arguments to your script don't have whitespace in them.
So we call `sh split.sh` which will basically execute the command by splitting arguments like `2222 --something` to `2222` and `--something`.
Those arguments will be passed to `python3 sample.py`, so you get a shell command like `python3 sample.py 2222 --something` that is run by `parallel`.

If we didn't use `split.sh` and just called python directly (`xargs -0 parallel python3 sample.py --`), then when `xargs` passes `2222 --something` as a single argument, `parallel` would have ran something like `python3 sample.py '2222 --something'`.